# Spring security with password encoding and salting

Tags: spring, spring-security, salt

I am trying to to authenticate user with spring-security with SHA hashing and salting. I have added extra field in users table for extra salt and customize `UserDetails` with this salt but whenever I try to login it is throwing bad credential exception.

My `CustomJdbcDaoImpl` class is :

```
public class CustomJdbcDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoImpl implements IChangePassword {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJdbcDaoImpl.class);
    

    @Override
    protected UserDetails createUserDetails(String username,UserDetails userFromUserQuery,
            List<GrantedAuthority> combinedAuthorities){
        String returnUsername = userFromUserQuery.getUsername();
        if(!isUsernameBasedPrimaryKey()){
            returnUsername = username;
        }
        logger.info("inside @class CustomJdbcDaoImpl @method createUserDetails USER DETAILS ARE: "+userFromUserQuery.getPassword()+"authritieds: "+combinedAuthorities);
        return new SaltedUser(returnUsername, 
                userFromUserQuery.getPassword(),
                userFromUserQuery.isEnabled(), 
                true,
                true, 
                true, 
                combinedAuthorities,
                ((SaltedUser)userFromUserQuery).getSalt());
         

    }

    @Override
    protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
        return getJdbcTemplate()
                .query(getUsersByUsernameQuery(), 
                        new String[] {username}, 
                        new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
                    public SaltedUser mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        String username = rs.getString(1);
                        String password = rs.getString(2);
                        boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean(3);
                        String salt = rs.getString(4);
                        SaltedUser saltedUser = new SaltedUser(username, password, enabled,
                                true, 
                                true,
                                true,
                                AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES, 
                                salt);
                        logger.info("inside @class @method loadUsersByUsername salted password  is: "+saltedUser.getPassword());
                        return saltedUser;
                    }
                    

                });
    }

    @Override
    public void changePassword(String username, String password) {
        getJdbcTemplate().
        update("update users set password = ? where username = ?",password,username);
        
    }

}
```

for changing password each time with salt my `DatabasePasswordSecurerBean` class is

```
public class DatabasePasswordSecurerBean extends JdbcDaoSupport {
    
        @Autowired
        private  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        
        @Autowired
        private SaltSource saltSource;
            
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        
        private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabasePasswordSecurerBean.class);
        
        public void secureDatabase(){
            logger.info("inside @class DatabasePasswordSecurerBean  @method secureDatabase entry...");
            getJdbcTemplate().query("select username,password from users",new RowCallbackHandler(){
    
                @Override
                public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                   String username = rs.getString(1);
                   String password = rs.getString(2);
                   
                   UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                   String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encodePassword(password,saltSource.getSalt(user));
                   getJdbcTemplate().update("update users set password = ? where username = ?",
                          encodedPassword,username);
                  
                 logger.info("@class DatabasePasswordSecurerBean  @method secureDatabase updating password for user: "+username + "to: "+encodedPassword);
                }
                  
                
            });
            
        }
        
    }

 security.xml configurations are 

    
   

     <http auto-config="true">
          <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        </http>
        
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
                <authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcUserService">
                  <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" >
                    <salt-source ref="saltSource" />
                  </password-encoder>
                  
                  
                  
                </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
        
            
        </beans:beans>
```

and my application.xml is

```
<!-- Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface,
                configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties -->
           <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
              <property name="url" value="${db.connection.url}" />
              <property name="username" value="${db.connection.username}" />
              <property name="password" value="${db.connection.password}" />
           </bean>
                                                                                 
           <bean id="jdbcUserService" class="com.petCart.springsecurity.security.CustomJdbcDaoImpl">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
              <property name="enableGroups" value="true"></property>
              <property name="enableAuthorities" value="false"></property>
              <property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
                    <value>
                       select username,password,enabled,salt from users where username = ?
                    </value>
              </property>
              <property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery">
                    <value>
                       select r.roleid,r.role_name,p.permissionname from roles r
                       join userrole ur on ur.roleid = r.roleid
                       join users u on u.id = ur.userid 
                       join rolepermission rp on r.roleid = rp.roleid 
                       join permissions p on p.permissionid = rp.permissionid
                       where u.username = ?
                    </value>
              </property>
          </bean>
          
          <!-- password encoder -->
           <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
           <bean class="com.petCart.springsecurity.security.DatabasePasswordSecurerBean"  init-method="secureDatabase" depends-on="dataSource">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
           </bean>
           <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" id="saltSource">
               <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username" />
           </bean>
```

Comment: i really mesh my holiday with all this stuff please some one help me...

Comment: probably not the answer you expect, but why don't you use BCrypt, which spring security provides already? it is stronger than SHA and also includes salt, and everything is managed by you, you only need to call the password encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" id="saltSource">
   <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username" />
</bean>
```

to

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" id="saltSource">
   <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="salt" />
</bean>
```